# From a UX point of view, what is the preferred way to develop cross platform apps in 2015?

Tags: mobile, web-app, user-expectation, cross-platform

My organization is looking to develop a cross-platform application.

I see that there are [a large number of frameworks](http://appindex.com/blog/ten-best-cross-platform-development-mobile-enterprises/) available that translate javascript of HTML5 code into native apps for iOS, Android and Windows mobile. **From a designer point of view, which of these frameworks are more flexible or easier to work with than others?**

I'm sure that all of these frameworks support basics like labels, text fields and buttons, but what about advanced features, like:

1. Custom transitions between screens
2. Animations (like material design)
3. Percentage/constraint based layouts
4. Ui responsiveness.
5. Availability of collections of reusable elements

   Maybe there's an infographic that compares frameworks like Phonegap, Xamarin, iFactr, etc in terms of what they can do ?

Answer (score 3):

Check out the [Ionic framework.](http://ionicframework.com/) It's a newer framework for hybrid apps that just hit 1.0. It's built on Angular, which means it's battle-tested in production apps, and easy to pick up if you're already familiar with the framework, as well as leveraging Cordova (PhoneGap) for cross-platform binaries. Angular has modules or components for everything you should be needing to do (ngAnimate, which lets you trigger CSS3 transitions from your Angular code will be very helpful to you, as well as directives for reusable code.)

It's fast, bugs get fixed very quickly, and the support staff is great. This is a web developer's framework for building apps, so it should fit into the 'designer' situation very well. Overall, would highly recommend based off my own experience, as well as the experience I have seen others have.